# is isnan preserved when asigning to different size FP type.

Tags: c++, nan, ieee-754

Basically:

```
float  nanf=std::numeric_limits::signaling_NaN<decltype(g_nanf)>();
double nand = nanf;
assert(std::isnan(nand));
```

can assert fire?
also what if I was assigning double nan to float

Comment: `decltype(g_nanf)` ? ITYM `float` ?

Answer (score 3):

From N3337:

> 4.6 Floating point promotion [conv.fpprom]
>
> 1 A prvalue of type `float` can be converted to a prvalue of type `double`. **The value is unchanged.**

,

> 4.8 Floating point conversions [conv.double]
>
> 1 A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating point
>   type. **If the source value can be exactly represented in the
>   destination type, the result of the conversion is that exact
>   representation.** If the source value is between two adjacent
>   destination values, the result of the conversion is an
>   implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise,
>   the behavior is undefined.

and

> 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]
>
> 8 There are three floating point types: `float`, `double`, and `long double`. The type `double` provides
>   at least as much precision as `float`, and the type `long double` provides
>   at least as much precision as `double`. **The set of values of the type
>   `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`**; the set of
>   values of the type `double` is a subset of the set of values of the type
>   `long double`.

Now we should confirm that `NaN` is in fact a valid *value* for a floating point type. The definition for `isnan` refers back to the `C` Standard. From N1570:

> 7.12.3.4 The `isnan` macro
>
> 2 The `isnan` macro determines whether its argument **value** is a NaN.

**So to summarise:** yes, going from `float` to `double` should preserve NaN-ness. Going from `double` to `float` is perhaps a little iffier, but as `double` supports NaN, we conclude that this conversion also must be preserved, by the "subset of values" wording.

([What the word "value" actually means seems to be somewhat ill-defined.](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/Sg2IRvV9jFo))

Comment: I think the proper standard would be IEEE 754 given the question tag.

Comment: @MSalters I think the quotes I have pasted show that this behaviour is required in C++ whether or not the floating point types follow IEEE 754. Hence this remains true when they do. But if you have access to IEEE 754 (Or a late draft or whatever. I don't have anything.) I would be interested to see an answer with the relevant quotes.

Comment: But IEEE 754 is a lot clearer about the meaning of "value" in floating-point contexts. E.g. `+0.0` and `-0.0` are definitely the same value according to IEEE754.

Comment: +1; I also provided the relevant IEEE-754 citation below for the curious.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't require adherence to IEEE-754; however, for platforms that do follow the standard, clause 6.2 governs the behavior for quiet NaNs:

> **For an operation with quiet NaN inputs**, other than maximum and minimum operations, if a floating-point result is to be delivered **the result shall be a quiet NaN**  ...

and signaling NaNs:

> Under default exception handling, any operation signaling an invalid operation exception and for which a floating-point result is to be delivered shall deliver a quiet NaN.
>
> Signaling NaNs shall be reserved operands that, under default exception handling, signal the invalid operation exception (see 7.2) for every general-computational and signaling-computational operation ...

Answer (score 0):

[BoBTFish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22019445/2230) sounds pretty convincing to me. Now, I don't have normative information on this subject myself, but I want to provide an alternative answer based on a bit of deduction:

It is generally true that:

- Generally speaking, any expression involving a `NaN` must return `NaN`.
- An arithmetic expression might involve casting from/to `single` and `double`, maybe multiple times.

I don't see how the compiler could could meet both requirements without preserving `NaN` during a `float`/`double` cast.